# jQuery - Change href attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, attr

I trying to change `href` via jQuery, but I don't know why it's not working...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var oldurl = $('`http://google.com`');
  var newurl = $('`http://yahoo.com`');

  $('a[href="' + oldurl + '"]').attr('href', newurl);

  // it's not working too...
  //$('a[href="http://google.com"]').attr('href', 'http://yahoo.com');

  // it's not working too...
  //$('.mylink').attr('href', newurl);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpM2U/3/)

Comment: You aren't closing the square bracket on this line: `$('a[href="' + oldurl + '"')`

Comment: right, i missed that, now added, but still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/vpM2U/3/

Comment: What do you expect `$('\`http://google.com\`')` to do? The argument to `$()` should either be a DOM selector (to find matching elements) or an HTML string (to create new elements). What are you trying to do by putting a URL there, and why the backtick around it?

Comment: nothing, it's just my mistake. anyway, thanks problem solved with answer below. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You just need:

```
var oldurl = 'http://google.com';
var newurl = 'http://yahoo.com';
$('a[href="' + oldurl + '"]').attr('href', newurl);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpM2U/4/)

Urls must be string and not `jQuery` objects and you forgot to close the square bracket.

Comment: I didn't DV, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968013/jquery-change-href-attr#comment36927145_23968013

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, yeah. Done